# close Excel from PowerBuilder

Tags: excel, disconnect

Working with PowerBuilder, I'm using an OLE object to make some changes in an Excel document, but when I disconnect the object, the Task Manager shown that it's still running.  Also, if I open another Excel document, I can then open the Excel document that I made changes in.

I've tried just about everything I have seen on here, but most are using C# or something other than PB.  The code that I've see and tried, doesn't run in PB.

Any ideas?

```
ole_excel = create oleobject
ole_excel.ConnectToNewObject("excel.application")

ole_excel.application.quit()
ole_excel.DisconnectObject()
```

In Task manager, I see the following:

```
EXCEL.EXE *32
```

Thanks,
Queue

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the process remained for whatever reason, I code a 
Garbagecollect()
and the process vanishes.

Take care.
Georg